# Table Value Parameter with Dapper stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dapper

I am attempting to call a stored procedure that accepts a table valued parameter.

I am following guidelines on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6232978/20048) question, implementing a custom parameter type:

```
internal class IntDynamicParam
{
    string name;
    IEnumerable<int> numbers;

    public IntDynamicParam(string name,IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public void AddParameters(IDbCommand command)
    {
        var sqlCommand = (SqlCommand)command;
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        List<Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlDataRecord> number_list = new List<Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlDataRecord>();

        // Create an SqlMetaData object that describes our table type.
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData[] tvp_definition = { new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData("n", SqlDbType.Int) };

        foreach (int n in numbers)
        {
            // Create a new record, using the metadata array above.
            Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlDataRecord rec = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlDataRecord(tvp_definition);
            rec.SetInt32(0, n);    // Set the value.
            number_list.Add(rec);      // Add it to the list.
        }

        // Add the table parameter.
        var p = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@" +name, SqlDbType.Structured);
        p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        p.TypeName = "int_list_type";
        p.Value = number_list;

    }
}
```

and am attempting to use this as follows:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
 p.AddDynamicParams(new IntDynamicParam("@IDList", new int[] { 1000, 2000, 3000 }));
 p.Add("@StartRow", startRow);
 p.Add("@EndRow", endRow);
 p.Add("@OrderByField", orderByField.ToString());
 p.Add("@OrderBy", orderBy.ToString());
 p.Add("@TotalRows", 0, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
 var v = cnn.Query<venue>(spName, p,
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList<IDBVenueLite>();
```

However the parameter '*@IDList*' is not passed. Clearly AddDynamicParams is not the way to go, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Found this older question that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232978/does-dapper-support-sql-2008-table-valued-parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Historically table-valued-parameters haven't been a huge focus in dapper; mainly because they only work on `SqlConnection` (dapper tries to target arbitrary providers, including "decorated" ADO.NET providers - i.e. where a `SqlConnection` is hiding underneath some wrapper). What you *could* do is implement `IDynamicParameters` manually (or just borrow the existing `DynamicParameters` class) to add this functionality:

```
void SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters.AddParameters(System.Data.IDbCommand command,
                                                SqlMapper.Identity identity)
{
    ...
    // and then whatever the code is...
    ((SqlCommand)command).Parameters
        .AddWithValue(...,...).SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
    ...
}
```

I will also endeavor to make the concrete `DynamicParameters` class more polymorphic here, so that in a future build you can just `override` a single method, detect a TVP-ish type, and add the parameter manually.

Comment: Thanks Marc, do you mean replace the AddParameters method in Dapper with my own implementation?

Comment: @Simon I mean: you can supply *any* `IDynamicParameters` implementation - you don't have to use the `DynamicParameters` class. It just needs to be able to add the parameters. Using the existing one as a model is probably easiest, though. It would be nice if you could inherit it and `override` the behavior per-parameter, but that isn't there right now.