# Error converting varchar to datetime when running stored procedure from code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

From within my C# app I'm calling a stored procedure using Dapper:

```
return conn.Query<MyList>("check_data", new { dataToCheck }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

`dataToCheck` is a `DataTable` because `check_data` accepts a `TVP`. This table type has 2 columns (from_date varchar(20), to_date varchar(20)) and is based on the following class.

```
public class DataToCheckType
{
    public DateTime? from_date {get; set;}
    public DateTime? to_date {get; set;}
}
```

Dapper then sends the following to SQL Server:

```
declare @p1 dbo.CheckDataType
insert into @p1 values('2017-04-19 00:00:00','2017-04-19 00:00:00')

exec check_data @dataToCheck=@p1
```

The SP itself is simple. It calls a function that builds a SQL statement which is then executed:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = dbo.GetSql(@dataToCheck);

DECLARE @results TABLE (Id int);
INSERT INTO @results EXECUTE(@sql);
```

The `GetSql` function starts like this:

```
DECLARE @fromDate datetime;
DECLARE @toDate datetime;

SELECT 
    @fromDate = CONVERT(datetime, from_date, 120),
    @toDate = CONVERT(datetime, to_date, 120),
FROM 
    @dataToCheck;
```

And it continues building the SQL statement as expected. When running the `SP` from `T-SQL` everything works fine.

However, when running the same from code I get the following error:

> check_data : 241 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Why does the SP work in T-SQL but not when calling it from code? What is wrong with the dates?

Comment: When you declare a variable include the TYPE.  I can't tell from you code what is a Varchar and what is a DataTime.

Comment: This line, `exec check_data @dataToCheck=@p1`, looks suspicious.  Specifically, the equal sign.

Comment: @DanBracuk That's what being generated and it works in TSQL. SP's dataToCheck parameter is set to p1 variable.

Comment: Does your table have the same columns with the same datatype as of the TableValueType in SQL? Looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042499/table-value-parameter-with-dapper-stored-procedures ??

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes because if this wasn't the case it would not work from T-SQL

Comment: Running from T-SQL and from C# code is different thing. In C# you need to create DataTable and add columns to it manually. If you have a mismatch there it will not run successfully. That's where is the possibility of getting conversion error. Can you share the code of how are you creating parameter object `dataToCheck` in C# ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I added the class to the question. Dapper generates this line `insert into @p1 values('2017-04-19 00:00:00','2017-04-19 00:00:00')` so it's quite happy with the conversion. And the error is converting from string to datetime not the other way round. I use an extension to create a `DataTable` from the object and it's used in many other places with success.

Comment: What is the type of parameter `dataToCheck`?

Comment: Are you sure that's what Dapper sends to SQL Server? It looks to me like the DataTable has `DateTime`s in it rather than strings so the format will probably not be the one you're expecting. It's hard to tell without seeing how you populate dataToCheck though...

Comment: Why your Table is `(from_date varchar(20), to_date varchar(20))` instead of `(from_date date, to_date date)`? Date formats depends on culture and `DATEFORMAT` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the columns in the table type from `varchar(20)` to `date`.