# Create an IN clause on the fly

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I have created a string of integers like this:

```
var whereClause = "4,5,6"
```

I need to use this in the following SQL `where` clause, where `message.Id` is an `int` col

```
select * from table a where message.Id in (@whereClause)
```

Running this throws **Conversion failed** when converting the `nvarchar` value '4,5,6' to data type `int`.

How would one cast the string, so that it could be used in a `WHERE IN` clause?

***EDIT***
Appreciate this could possible be a repeat of a question, but I am using Dapper.NET and couldn't find any examples

Comment: No way to use a parameter to express a list of integers. It will be treated as a string

Comment: Can you just use it as a collection? `var options = whereClause.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: specifically see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/961113

Comment: Do you execute that sql in a stored procedure? You could create the sql string in C# (when you are certain you control where the integesers come from so you don;t expose yourself to SQL injection.

Comment: i have provided an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748327/how-to-write-stored-procedure-for-my-candidate-using-case-which-includes-skillid/21753829#21753829), check it out, it may be useful to you

Comment: @Habib: it's worth noting that the third answer (acc. to the upvotes)  using table-valued-parameters is the best approach if OP uses SQL-Server (>= 2008).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes, but may be a bit complicated to understand first but definitely a better option.

Comment: Gents, I'm using Dapper.NET, so not sure how role in table-valued-parameters

Comment: @CSharpNewBee: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232978/does-dapper-support-sql-2008-table-valued-parameters

Comment: Thanks @Tim, may approach this differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting article [Using comma separated value parameter strings in SQL IN clauses](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/584680/Using-comma-separated-value-parameter-strings-in-S):

```
DECLARE @LIST VARCHAR(200)
SET @LIST = '1,3'
SELECT Id, Descr FROM CSVDemo WHERE Id IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@LIST))
```

Comment: Garath, can this be done without using the SQL function? From what you guys are posting, i believe not.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it like this: each item of the `IN` list needs to be bound individually.

First, you need to generate a SQL string with the proper number of parameters, like this:

```
select * from table a where message.Id in (@w1, @w2, @w3)
```

After that you need to bind each `@wN` individually.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
exec ('select * from table a where message.Id in ('+@whereClause+')'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use dynamic query but it could create some headaches in future, because the maintenance could be hard. The dynamic query should look like this:

```
SET @IDs = '4,5,6' 
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ID IN(' + @IDs + ')'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```