# update N rows with performance considerations

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I have a table with OrderSequence, the schema looks roughly like this:

- id
- Name
- OrderSequence

I have an arrays of ids ("1", "2", "3", "4") in my MVC Action codes, i want to set the SequenceOrder for sorting purpose. I don't want to loop it via .Net and execute N number of sql queries. How should i do it using dapper/raw ado.net?

Comment: Not with Dapper, but with ADO.NET. Look into structured parameters for Stored Procedures and how to pass them. You basically will send your whole array at once to a SP as a table-valued variable and then do an `UPDATE FROM` to update your table. So, only one roundtrip to the database.

Comment: i know that dapper can execute arbitary sql statements, can it be done that way?

Comment: Yes, but that means to have the update query hardcoded somewhere in your app and just pass the array in a `WHERE ... IN (...)` statement. All in all, a lot uglier than structured params.

Comment: @marceln i don't mind having hardcoded query in this instance, do you have a sample?

Comment: Is the SequenceOrder just going to be incrementing from some start position? Meaning: what are the expected OrderSequence values at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper can do that via:

```
connection.Execute("update Orders set Sequence=@seq where Id=@id",
            ids.Select((id, seq) => new { id, seq }));
```

However, this is just using dapper to unroll a loop - in reality it is calling `Execute` per row on your behalf, exactly the same as if you had done:

```
int seq = 0;
foreach(var id in ids) {
    connection.Execute("update Orders set Sequence=@seq where Id=@id",
         new { id, seq });
    seq++;
}
```

If you want to pass all the data down in one go, you could look at table-valued-parameters, [which dapper supports in recent builds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24633764/23354).

Comment: it's to pass values to storedprocs?

Comment: Great, I didn't know they already released that. Time for some updates.

Comment: If I were to use your answer in a transaction will it hurt as much? I'm only updating < 15 rows

Comment: @Lee the stored procs vs command text debate is unrelated - dapper works fine with either