# Dapper Dynamic Parameters with Table Valued Parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable, dapper

I was trying to create a generic method, which can read the parameters name and value from a class at Runtime and create parameter collection for Dapper query execution. Realized that till the point all parameters are Input type it works well, but if I have to add an `Output / ReturnValue` type parameters, then I need to work with `DynamicParameters`, else I cannot fetch the value of `Output / ReturnValue` parameters

SP has following parameters:

```
PersonList - TableValued - Input
TestOutput - Int - Output
```

I am not able to make following piece of code work:

```
var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
dynamicParameters.Add("PersonList", <DataTable PersonList>);
dynamicParameters.Add("TestOutput", 0, Dbtype.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Exception is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS)
>        remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 
>       ("@PersonList"): Data type 0x62 (sql_variant) has an invalid type for type-
>       specific metadata.

Issue as I can understand is there's no valid DbType available for adding a TVP to the Dynamic Parameters, since I am not using the SqlDbType, so there's no replacement for SqlDbType.Structured in the DbType.

Any pointer or workaround to resolve the issue

Comment: Apparently by default there's no access to Parameter Collection using IDbConnection in the Dapper, so using a standard mechanism, I cannot access the Output / ReturnValue parameters

Comment: Try out this solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232978/does-dapper-support-sql-2008-table-valued-parameters

Comment: @SalmanSyed thanks for the details, but it would be too cumbersome to keep creating helpers for each relevant type, my custom solution underneath is much more generic to do the same task

Answer (score 18):

First create a User Defined Table type in Database

```
CREATE TYPE udtt_PersonList AS TABLE 
(
    ...
)
GO
```

In your code

```
var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
dynamicParameters.Add("@PersonList", PersonList.AsTableValuedParameter("[dbo].[udtt_PersonList]"));
dynamicParameters.Add("TestOutput", 0, Dbtype.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Comment: Just what I needed, for clarity for the next person PersonList is of Type DataTable.

Comment: AsTableValuedParameter does not exist in dapper v2.0.90

Answer (score 3):

Inside the add function of parameter object pass argument DbType.Object

eg:

```
DynamicParameters parameterObject = new DynamicParameters();
parameterObject.Add("@table", dtTable, DbType.Object);
```

Comment: ha ha ha, This answer has no votes and not highlighted even, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

As I can understand that this requirement is not supported out of the box and I may need to code the specific helper. I have resolved it using a custom base abstract class `TypeMap`, which can be extended by all kinds of providers, to implement the API, which are not out of he box possible using the Dapper, I am pasting my implementation related to SQL-Server, similar can be done for other ADO.Net compliant providers:

```
namespace Dapper
{
    #region NameSpaces

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;

    #endregion


        /// <summary>
        ///     Type Map class for database provider specific code
        /// </summary>
        internal abstract class TypeMap
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Only Non Input Parameters collection
            /// </summary>
            public abstract Dictionary<string, object> NonInputParameterCollection { get; set; } 

            /// <summary>
            /// Method to execute the DML via TypeMap
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="connection"></param>
            /// <param name="sql"></param>
            /// <param name="commandType"></param>
            /// <param name="dapperParams"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public abstract int Execute(IDbConnection connection, 
                                        string sql, 
                                        CommandType commandType,
                                        IEnumerable<DapperParam> dapperParams );

            /// <summary>
            /// Method to execute the Select to fetch IEnumerable via TypeMap
            /// </summary>
            /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
            /// <param name="connection"></param>
            /// <param name="sql"></param>
            /// <param name="commandType"></param>
            /// <param name="dapperParams"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public abstract IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(IDbConnection connection,
                                                    string sql,
                                                    CommandType commandType,
                                                    IEnumerable<DapperParam> dapperParams) where T : new();

            /// <summary>
            /// Fetch the relevant TypeMap
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="provider"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static TypeMap GetTypeMap(string provider)
            {
                TypeMap typeMap = null;

                switch (provider)
                {
                    case "System.Data.SqlClient":
                        typeMap = new SqlTypeMap();
                        break;
                    default:
                        // SQl Server TypeMap
                        typeMap = new SqlTypeMap();
                        break;
                }

                return (typeMap);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     SQL Server provider type map
        /// </summary>
        internal class SqlTypeMap : TypeMap
        {
            public SqlTypeMap()
            {
                NonInputParameterCollection = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            }

            public override sealed Dictionary<string, object> NonInputParameterCollection { get; set; } 

            public override int Execute(IDbConnection connection,
                                        string sql,
                                        CommandType commandType,
                                        IEnumerable<DapperParam> dapperParams)
            {
                int returnValue = -1;

                var sqlConnection = (connection as SqlConnection) ?? new SqlConnection();

                using (sqlConnection)
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = null;

                    sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();

                    using (sqlCommand)
                    {
                        // public SqlParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType, int size, ParameterDirection direction, byte precision, byte scale, string sourceColumn, DataRowVersion sourceVersion, bool sourceColumnNullMapping, object value, string xmlSchemaCollectionDatabase, string xmlSchemaCollectionOwningSchema, string xmlSchemaCollectionName);
                        foreach (var param in dapperParams)
                        {
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                            {
                                ParameterName = param.ParamName,
                                SqlValue = param.ParamValue ?? DBNull.Value,
                                SqlDbType = TypeToSqlDbType[param.ParamType],
                                Direction = Map.DirectionMap[param.ParamDirection]
                            });
                        }

                        sqlCommand.CommandText = sql; // Assign Sql Text
                        sqlCommand.CommandType = commandType; // Assign CommandType
                        sqlCommand.Connection.Open(); // Explicitly open connection to use it with SqlCommand object
                        returnValue = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Execute Query

                        foreach (SqlParameter param in sqlCommand.Parameters.Cast<SqlParameter>().Where(param => param.Direction != ParameterDirection.Input))
                            NonInputParameterCollection.Add(param.ParameterName, param.Value);
                    }
                }

                return (returnValue);
            }

            public override IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(IDbConnection connection,
                                      string sql,
                                      CommandType commandType,
                                      IEnumerable<DapperParam> dapperParams)
            {
                IEnumerable<T> returnEnumerable = null;

                var sqlConnection = (connection as SqlConnection) ?? new SqlConnection();

                using (sqlConnection)
                {
                    var sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();

                    using (sqlCommand)
                    {
                        foreach (var param in dapperParams)
                        {
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                            {
                                ParameterName = param.ParamName,
                                SqlValue = param.ParamValue ?? DBNull.Value,
                                SqlDbType = TypeToSqlDbType[param.ParamType],
                                Direction = Map.DirectionMap[param.ParamDirection]
                            });
                        }

                        sqlCommand.CommandText = sql; // Assign Sql Text
                        sqlCommand.CommandType = commandType; // Assign CommandType

                        var sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

                        var returnDataTable = new DataTable();

                        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(returnDataTable);

                        returnEnumerable = Common.ToList<T>(returnDataTable);

                        foreach (SqlParameter param in sqlCommand.Parameters.Cast<SqlParameter>()
                                                                 .Where(param => param.Direction != ParameterDirection.Input))
                            NonInputParameterCollection.Add(param.ParameterName, param.Value);
                    }
                }

                return (returnEnumerable);
            }

            /// <summary>
            ///     Data Type to Db Type mapping dictionary for SQL Server
            /// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx
            /// </summary>

            public static readonly Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType> TypeToSqlDbType = new Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType>
            {
              // Mapping C# types to Ado.net SqlDbType enumeration
                {typeof (byte), SqlDbType.TinyInt},
                {typeof (sbyte), SqlDbType.TinyInt},
                {typeof (short), SqlDbType.SmallInt},
                {typeof (ushort), SqlDbType.SmallInt},
                {typeof (int), SqlDbType.Int},
                {typeof (uint), SqlDbType.Int},
                {typeof (long), SqlDbType.BigInt},
                {typeof (ulong), SqlDbType.BigInt},
                {typeof (float), SqlDbType.Float},
                {typeof (double), SqlDbType.Float},
                {typeof (decimal), SqlDbType.Decimal},
                {typeof (bool), SqlDbType.Bit},
                {typeof (string), SqlDbType.VarChar},
                {typeof (char), SqlDbType.Char},
                {typeof (Guid), SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier},
                {typeof (DateTime), SqlDbType.DateTime},
                {typeof (DateTimeOffset), SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset},
                {typeof (byte[]), SqlDbType.VarBinary},
                {typeof (byte?), SqlDbType.TinyInt},
                {typeof (sbyte?), SqlDbType.TinyInt},
                {typeof (short?), SqlDbType.SmallInt},
                {typeof (ushort?), SqlDbType.SmallInt},
                {typeof (int?), SqlDbType.Int},
                {typeof (uint?), SqlDbType.Int},
                {typeof (long?), SqlDbType.BigInt},
                {typeof (ulong?), SqlDbType.BigInt},
                {typeof (float?), SqlDbType.Float},
                {typeof (double?), SqlDbType.Float},
                {typeof (decimal?), SqlDbType.Decimal},
                {typeof (bool?), SqlDbType.Bit},
                {typeof (char?), SqlDbType.Char},
                {typeof (Guid?), SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier},
                {typeof (DateTime?), SqlDbType.DateTime},
                {typeof (DateTimeOffset?), SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset},
                {typeof (System.Data.Linq.Binary), SqlDbType.Binary},
                {typeof (IEnumerable<>), SqlDbType.Structured},
                {typeof (List<>), SqlDbType.Structured},
                {typeof (DataTable), SqlDbType.Structured},

            };



        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public static class Map
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public static Dictionary<Type, DbType> TypeToDbType = new Dictionary<Type, DbType>()
        {
            {typeof (byte), DbType.Byte},
            {typeof (sbyte), DbType.Byte},
            {typeof (short), DbType.Int16},
            {typeof (ushort), DbType.Int16},
            {typeof (int), DbType.Int32},
            {typeof (uint), DbType.Int32},
            {typeof (long), DbType.Int64},
            {typeof (ulong), DbType.Int64},
            {typeof (float), DbType.Single},
            {typeof (double), DbType.Double},
            {typeof (decimal), DbType.Decimal},
            {typeof (bool), DbType.Boolean},
            {typeof (string), DbType.String},
            {typeof (char), DbType.StringFixedLength},
            {typeof (Guid), DbType.Guid},
            {typeof (DateTime), DbType.DateTime},
            {typeof (DateTimeOffset), DbType.DateTimeOffset},
            {typeof (byte[]), DbType.Binary},
            {typeof (byte?), DbType.Byte},
            {typeof (sbyte?), DbType.Byte},
            {typeof (short?), DbType.Int16},
            {typeof (ushort?), DbType.Int16},
            {typeof (int?), DbType.Int32},
            {typeof (uint?), DbType.Int32},
            {typeof (long?), DbType.Int64},
            {typeof (ulong?), DbType.Int64},
            {typeof (float?), DbType.Single},
            {typeof (double?), DbType.Double},
            {typeof (decimal?), DbType.Decimal},
            {typeof (bool?), DbType.Boolean},
            {typeof (char?), DbType.StringFixedLength},
            {typeof (Guid?), DbType.Guid},
            {typeof (DateTime?), DbType.DateTime},
            {typeof (DateTimeOffset?), DbType.DateTimeOffset},
            {typeof (System.Data.Linq.Binary), DbType.Binary}
        };

        /// <summary>
        ///     Parameter Direction for Stored Procedure
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly Dictionary<string, ParameterDirection> DirectionMap =
               new Dictionary<string, ParameterDirection>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            {
                {ParamDirectionConstants.Input, ParameterDirection.Input},
                {ParamDirectionConstants.Output, ParameterDirection.Output},
                {ParamDirectionConstants.InputOutput, ParameterDirection.InputOutput},
                {ParamDirectionConstants.ReturnValue, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue}
            };
    }
}
```

Supporting classes and API, to make the above code work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Dapper
{
    public class DapperParam
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Parameter Type Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="paramName"></param>
        /// <param name="paramType"></param>
        /// <param name="paramDirection"></param>
        /// <param name="paramValue"></param>
        public DapperParam(string paramName,
                        Type paramType,
                        string paramDirection,
                        object paramValue)
        {
            ParamName = paramName;
            ParamType = paramType;
            ParamDirection = paramDirection;
            ParamValue = paramValue;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Parameter name
        /// </summary>
        public string ParamName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Parameter Type
        /// </summary>
        public Type ParamType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Parameter Direction
        /// </summary>
        public string ParamDirection { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Parameter Value
        /// </summary>
        public object ParamValue { get; set; }

    }

    internal static class DataConversionMap
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Type conversion, handles null
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <param name="func"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static object ConvertDbData(object obj, Func<object> func)
        {
            return (!Convert.IsDBNull(obj)) ? func() : null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Dictionary map to convert to a given DataType. Returns a Func of object,object.
        ///     Internally calls ConvertDbData for Data Type conversion
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> Map =
            new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>
            {
                {
                    typeof(Int16),
                    objectValue => ConvertDbData(objectValue, () => Convert.ToInt16(objectValue))
                },

                {
                    typeof(Int32),
                    objectValue => ConvertDbData(objectValue, () => Convert.ToInt32(objectValue))
                },

                {
                    typeof(Int64),
                    objectValue => ConvertDbData(objectValue, () => Convert.ToInt64(objectValue))
                },

                {
                    typeof(Boolean),
                    objectValue => ConvertDbData(objectValue, () => Convert.ToBoolean(objectValue))
                },

                {
                    typeof(string),
                    objectValue => ConvertDbData(objectValue, () => Convert.ToString(objectValue))
                },

                {
                   typeof(DateTime), objectValue =>

                        ConvertDbData(objectValue, () =>
                        {
                            DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(objectValue);

                            if (dateTime.TimeOfDay.Equals(TimeSpan.Zero))
                                return dateTime.ToShortDateString();

                            return dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
                        })

                },

                {
                    typeof(Byte),
                    objectValue => ConvertDbData(objectValue, () => Convert.ToByte(objectValue))
                },

                {
                    typeof(Double),
                    objectValue => ConvertDbData(objectValue, () => Convert.ToDouble(objectValue))
                },

                {
                    typeof(Decimal),
                    objectValue => ConvertDbData(objectValue, () => Convert.ToDecimal(objectValue))
                },

                {
                    typeof(TimeSpan),
                    objectValue => ConvertDbData(objectValue, () => TimeSpan.Parse(objectValue.ToString()))
                },

                {
                    typeof(Guid),
                    objectValue => ConvertDbData(objectValue, () => new Guid(objectValue.ToString()))
                },

                {
                    typeof(Byte[]),
                    objectValue => ConvertDbData(objectValue, () => (Byte[])(objectValue))
                }
            };
    }
}
```

Common APIs

```
public static class Common
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Convert IEnumerable<T> to DataTable
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="collection"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DataTable CreateTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            // Fetch the type of List contained in the ParamValue
            var tableType = typeof(T);

            // Create DataTable which will contain data from List<T>
            var dataTable = new DataTable();

            // Fetch the Type fields count
            int columnCount = tableType.GetProperties().Count();

            var columnNameMappingDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // Create DataTable Columns using table type field name and their types
            // Traversing through Column Collection
            for (int counter = 0; counter < columnCount; counter++)
            {
                var propertyInfo = tableType.GetProperties()[counter];

                var parameterAttribute = propertyInfo.GetParameterAttribute();

                string columnName = (parameterAttribute != null) ? parameterAttribute.Name : propertyInfo.Name;

                columnNameMappingDictionary.Add(propertyInfo.Name,
                    (parameterAttribute != null) ? parameterAttribute.Name : propertyInfo.Name);

                dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, tableType.GetProperties()[counter].PropertyType);
            }

            // Return parameter with null value
            if (collection == null)
                return dataTable;

            // Traverse through number of entries / rows in the List
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                // Create a new DataRow
                DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                // Traverse through type fields or column names
                for (int counter = 0; counter < columnCount; counter++)
                {
                    // Fetch Column Name
                    string columnName = columnNameMappingDictionary[tableType.GetProperties()[counter].Name];

                    //Fetch Value for each column for each element in the List<T>
                    dataRow[columnName] = item
                        .GetType().GetProperties()[counter]
                        .GetValue(item);
                }
                // Add Row to Table
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }

            return (dataTable);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert IEnumerable<T> to DataTable
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="paramValue"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DataTable CreateTable(object paramValue)
        {
            // Fetch the type of List contained in the ParamValue
            Type tableType = paramValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

            // Create DataTable which will contain data from List<T>
            var genericDataTable = new DataTable();

            // Fetch the Type fields count
            int fieldCount = tableType.GetProperties().Count();

            // Create DataTable Columns using table type field name and their types
            // Traversing through Column Collection
            for (int counter = 0; counter < fieldCount; counter++)
            {
                genericDataTable.Columns.Add(tableType.GetProperties()[counter].Name,
                    tableType.GetProperties()[counter].PropertyType);
            }

            // Traverse through number of entries / rows in the List
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)paramValue)
            {
                // Create a new DataRow
                DataRow dataRow = genericDataTable.NewRow();

                // Traverse through type fields or column names
                for (int counter = 0; counter < fieldCount; counter++)
                {
                    // Fetch Column Name
                    string columnName = tableType.GetProperties()[counter].Name;

                    //Fetch Value for each column for each element in the List<T>
                    dataRow[columnName] = item
                        .GetType().GetProperties()[counter]
                        .GetValue(item);
                }
                // Add Row to Table
                genericDataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }
            return genericDataTable;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert DataTable to List<T>
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="dataTable"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<T> ToList<T>(DataTable dataTable) where T : new()
        {
            // Final result List (Converted from DataTable)
            var convertedList = new List<T>();

            // Traverse through Rows in the DataTable
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                // Type T of generic list object
                var dataObject = new T();

                // Traverse through Columns in the DataTable
                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    // Fetch column name
                    string fieldName = column.ColumnName;

                    // Fetch type PropertyInfo using reflection
                    var propertyInfo = dataObject.GetType()
                        .GetProperty(fieldName,
                            BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                    // For Null PropertyInfo, check whether ViewrColumn attribute is applied
                    propertyInfo = propertyInfo ?? Parameter.GetColumnAttribute(dataObject.GetType(), fieldName);

                    // Set the value for not null property Info
                    // Continue the loop for a null PropertyInfo (needs correction either in type description or DataTable selection)
                    if (propertyInfo == null) continue;

                    // Property value
                    var value = row[column];

                    // New - Work for Nullable Types
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(dataObject,
                        DataConversionMap.Map[propertyInfo.PropertyType](value), null);
                }

                // Add type object to the List
                convertedList.Add(dataObject);
            }

            return (convertedList);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found Rohit Shetty's answer helpful, but still had trouble as it did not provide a complete example. Here is an example with more sample code.

In SQL, define your User Defined Table Type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntListTableType]
AS TABLE
(
    [Value] INT NOT NULL
);
```

Then in C# you would do something like this:

```
List<int> employeeIds = GetEmployeeIds();
...
// Create and populate the table type for the stored procedure.
DataTable employeeIdsTable = new DataTable();
employeeIdsTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
foreach (var employeeId in employeeIds)
{
    employeeIdsTable.Rows.Add(employeeId);
}

var storedProcedure = "[dbo].[GetEmployeesById]";
var storedProcedureParameters = new DynamicParameters();
storedProcedureParameters.Add("@EmployeeIds", employeeIdsTable.AsTableValuedParameter());

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(databaseConnectionString))
{
    var results = await connection.QueryAsync<IEnumerable<Employee>>(storedProcedure, storedProcedureParameters, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 60);
    return results;
}
```

You can optionally provide the name of the User Defined Table Type (e.g. `[dbo].[IntListTableType]`) in the `AsTableValuedParameter` method, but I found it worked fine without it in my scenario, so I'm not certain when it would be required.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TYPE [Common].[IDList] AS TABLE([ID] [int] NULL)
GO
```

```cs
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.Server;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using static Dapper.SqlMapper;

namespace Test
{
    public class TableOfIntegersTypeHandler : ITypeHandler
    {
        public object Parse(Type destinationType, object value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, object value)
        {
            var p = (SqlParameter)parameter;
            p.TypeName = "Common.IDList";
            p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            p.Value = AsSqlDataRecords((IEnumerable)value);
        }

        private static List<SqlDataRecord> AsSqlDataRecords(IEnumerable collection, string columnName = "ID")
        {
            var records = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
            var meta = new SqlMetaData[] { new SqlMetaData(columnName, SqlDbType.Int) };
            foreach (var num in collection)
            {
                var record = new SqlDataRecord(meta);
                if (num is null)
                {
                    record.SetDBNull(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    record.SetInt32(0, (int)num);
                }

                records.Add(record);
            }

            return records;
        }

        private static DataTable AsDataTable(IEnumerable collection, string columnName = "ID")
        {
            var tvp = new DataTable();
            var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(columnName, enumerator.Current.GetType()));

                do
                {
                    tvp.Rows.Add(enumerator.Current);
                }
                while (enumerator.MoveNext());
            }

            return tvp;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Dapper;

namespace Test
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var typeHandler = new TableOfIntegersTypeHandler();
            SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(int[]), typeHandler);
            SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(int?[]), typeHandler);
            SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(List<int>), typeHandler);
            SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(List<int?>), typeHandler);
            SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(IEnumerable<int>), typeHandler);
            SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(typeof(IEnumerable<int?>), typeHandler);

            try
            {
                using var con = new SqlConnection(...);
                con.Open();

                var ps = new DynamicParameters();
                ps.Add("@Ids", new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }));

                var ids = con.Query<int>("select * from @Ids", ps);

                ids = con.Query<int>("select * from @Ids", new { Ids = new[] { 1, 2 } });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reached here as I had the same problem - Wanted to call a StoredProcedure passing in a TABLE TYPE parameter to implement BulkInsert

The solution makes use of the Dapper.ParameterExtensions NuGet.

Steps for me were:

1. Create the UserDefinedTableType

   ```
    CREATE TYPE [core].[DataErrorType] AS TABLE (
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [SubmissionResponseErrorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Severity] [int] NULL,
    [RecordReferenceId] [int] NOT NULL)
   ```
2. Create the Stored Procedure

   ```
    CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [core].[spBulkInsertDataErrors]
    (
        @dataErrors [core].[DataErrorType] READONLY
    )
    AS
    INSERT INTO [core].[DataError] ([SubmissionResponseErrorId], [ErrorCode], [Severity], [RecordReferenceId])
    SELECT [SubmissionResponseErrorId], [ErrorCode], [Severity], [RecordReferenceId] 
    FROM @dataErrors
   ```
3. In the C# code, make use of the AddTable() extension method of DynamicParameters. The method can be found in DapperParameters NuGet package: [Dapper.ParameterExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.ParameterExtensions)

   ```
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.AddTable("@dataErrors", "core.DataErrorType", dataErrors);
    await sql.ExecuteAsync("[core].[spBulkInsertDataErrors]", parameters, transaction, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
   ```