# Send list of int to sql sp throught dapper dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, dapper, dynamicparameters

I need to call a sql stored procedure which have an input parameter with type "IntList" that is a user-defined table type,I wanna set this parameter with a list of int through dapper dynamic parameter, in this case I don't have Structured dbtype, how can I handle it? I've tried this :

```
   using var connection = _dbConnectionFactory.GetDefaultServerConnectionString();

            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@RequestId", query.RequestId, DbType.DateTime);
            parameters.Add("@Agencies", query.AgencyIds);

            return await connection.QueryAsync<TerminalDto>(
                "SelectTerminals", parameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

but it raise "too many arguments" error!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dapper Dynamic Parameters with Table Valued Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087629/dapper-dynamic-parameters-with-table-valued-parameters) Use `.AsTableValuedParameter("yourTableType")`