# Pass an array of complex objects to a stored procedure with dapper

Tags: stored-procedures, dapper

I am assisting someone on a dapper related integration and there is currently a scenario where we have some data that we need to get into a stored procedure. So we can write the stored procedure however we want, and can write the dapper bit however we want, but the object would look something like:

```
public class SomeComplexObject
{
   public string Something {get; set;}
   public string SomethingElse {get;set;}
}
```

This would be within an array with anywhere from 1-N amounts of these objects. So we need to pass these to a stored proc for it to use as part of its internal query stuffs.

So if I were to do something like:

```
new SqlParameter("arrayOfGoodies", arrayOfComplexObjects);
```

However it gives us the error:

> No mapping exists from object type

This makes sense as how would it know how to convert this array of Pocos into something for the SQL world, but somehow I need to get this data into the stored procedure. So is there a way to do this, by either telling dapper about this type, or possibly using one of those table value parameter things or something?

Answer (score 2):

I found way for PostgreSQL.

For explain,select list of users with the specified ID and Login.

in DB:

```
create table user_apt
(
    id bigint,
    login varchar(100),
    owner_name varchar(500),
    password varchar(50),
    is_active boolean,
    date_edit timestamp default now()
);

create type  t_user_test AS
(
  id bigint,
  login varchar(100),
  owner_name varchar(500)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_pass_object_array(i_users t_user_test)
  RETURNS SETOF t_user_test
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  return query
  SELECT
    ua.id,
    ua.login,
    ua.owner_name
  FROM user_apt ua
  inner join i_users inp ON ua.id=inp.id AND ua.login=inp.login;
END
$$;
```

In C#

```
using Dapper;
using Npgsql;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

namespace DapperSPWithClass
{
    public class User
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Owner_Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=test;User     Id=My;Password=SuperSecretPass;Timeout=15;";
            var lsUser = new List<User> {
            new User{
                ID=13,
                Login="kos@test5"
            },
            new User{
                ID=29,
                Login="nsk@autotest1"
            }};

            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                conn.TypeMapper.MapComposite<User>("t_user_test"); // Here is the magic we needed
                var res = conn.Query<User>("test_pass_object_array", commandType:     CommandType.StoredProcedure, param: new { i_users = lsUser });

            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
}
```

}

```
conn.TypeMapper.MapComposite<T>("t_user_test");
```

I found MapComposite in the article https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the array as Table Valued Parameter. Unfortunately you would have to convert it into a DataTable first.

For example:

```
    conn.Execute("My_SP", new { values = myTable.AsTableValuedParameter("MyType") }, 
commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Some more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232978/does-dapper-support-sql-2008-table-valued-parameters)